# php session variable not working in new subfolers

Tags: php, session-variables, subdirectory

i was developing my php application and using mysql to store session data and $_SESSION was working fine in both root and subfolers. but now when i create **new subfolers** , writing sessions works in them but i can't read the sessions . for example

```
$_SESSION['username'] = 'james';
```

it works fine and both session_id and session_data are stored in my mysql session table.
and the session id stored in my browser matches the id in table but when i want to use it(read data from mysql) it doesn't work in **new subfolers** . for example:

```
echo $_SESSION['username'];
```

it doesn't work.
and it's funny because when i copy the file in my previous subfolers it works all fine.
and i don't use .htaccess in my subfolers.

really confused. thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably missing `session_start();` on one or more pages.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Edit: 
Like Zanrok said, it's hard to diagnose your problem without seeing any of your code.

Comment: Without seeing more of the code, I would have to take the same guess.  Or possibly an included file linked wrong because of the directory switch?

Comment: read my question completely . i said 1) writing session data works . it means i didn't miss session_start() . 2) when i copy the file in previous subfolders it works fine while both subfolers are completely similar except for their names!

Comment: Why is this answer marked as correct when it suggests you do something you claim you've already done?